# genomatix software linux install

Tags: sequence-analysis, microarray

I have installed the genomatix software which is a jar file the name is InstallChipInspector21.jar.But now I really don;t know how do I start it ,can any one suggest me a method??

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a computer package installation. Refer to the readme associated with the package for details on this or contact the developer.

Comment: well it's not about installation I have installed it I need to run the program,that is what I'm asking for

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what else to say as an answer but [here is a link](https://www.genomatix.de/download/software/ChipInspector_Manual_V2.pdf) to the user manual. If you are looking for more specific usage instructions, I would suggest that you try [Biostars](https://www.biostars.org/) though I can't guarantee that you receive an answer.

Comment: I have seen the pdf it doesn't talk about how to start the program...

Comment: @krushna Try the command java -jar InstallChipInspector21.jar ?

Comment: yeah I have installed the software using the command but I need to run it how do I do that??